# Nonnegative partial derivalives a.e. and monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a locally Lipschitz function. Then by Rademacher's theorem $f$ is a.e. differentiable. Assume that $\frac {\partial f(x)} {\partial x_i} \geq 0$ for all $i=1,...,n$ whenever $f$ is differentiable at $x$. Is $f$ nondecreasing with respect to all the variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be the set of nondifferentiability points of $f$. For almost every line segment $L$ parallel to a coordinate axes, the intersection $L\cap N$ has zero 1-dimensional measure. Hence, the derivative of the restriction of $f$ to this segment at a.e. point comes from the derivative of $f$. Hence, the derivative of restriction is nonnegative.

Also, the restriction of $f$ to every line segment is Lipschitz, hence absolutely continuous. An absolutely continuous function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ with nonnegative derivative satisfies
$$f(x) = f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt \ge f(a)$$
(Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies to absolutely continuous functions.)

Comment: Thank you. But how can we arrive that the restriction of $f$ has a.e. nonnegative derivative? The intersection of the set, where (unrestricted) $f$ is differentiable, and the line segment may not be of full measure in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mikhail Good point; edited in.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So, if I understand correctly, you prove that $f$ is nondecreasing on almost all lines parallel to a coordinate axis and then use continuity to show that $f$ is nondecreasing on each line.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, that's what I meant.